# Import and Export Wizard from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. I'm trying to put it on SQL Azure. I have the table schemas already put in SQL Azure. I was hoping to use the Import/Export wizard to migrate my database. However, after I choose a destination in the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard and click "Next", I receive an error that says:

```
TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

Cannot get the supported data types from the database connection "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=tcp:[server],1433;User ID=[userID];Auto Translate=false;Initial Catalog=[dbName]".

Unspecified error
The stored procedure required to complete this operation could not be found on the server. Please contact your system administrator. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of SSMS: SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you might be using some other data provider then **.Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer as the Data Source** in your SQL Server Import and Export Wizard application. This is most common problem who use SQL Server Import/Export Wizard. Please try the fix as described below:

- http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/index.php/2011/10/importing-data-into-sql-azure/

More info about using SQL Server Import/Export Wizard is here:

1. [SQL Azure Data Migration Using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (en-US)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2287.sql-azure-data-migration-using-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard-en-us.aspx)
2. [Overview of Options for Migrating Data and Schema to SQL Azure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/overview-of-options-for-migrating-data-and-schema-to-sql-azure.aspx#migrationwiz)